# rings problem-- Consider the equation x^2+y^2=n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the equation $x^2+y^2=n$

1. find all solution to $x^2+y^2=2$
2. suppose that $n$ is a positive integer congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. Prove
   that the equation $x^2 + y^2 = n$ has no such integer solutions.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ in (1)?  Integers?

Answer (score 0):

For part 1, since both $x^2,y^2\ge 0$ the only possibility is that $x^2=y^2=1$ which implies that $x=\pm 1, y=\pm 1$.

For part 2, the only squares mod $4$ are $0,1$. So $x^2,y^2\equiv 0,1$ (mod $4$). There is now no possible combination that will give us $x^2+y^2\equiv 3$ (mod $4$) so $n\not\equiv 3$ (mod $4$).